# When selecting a file, the File upload input doesn't update the value

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload

I'm using Javascript to dynamically add floor plans where a user can add and attach images  to hotel floors.

How do I make the File upload input update it's value to what the user chose?

if the button is set on page load, it works fine, but if it's generated by Javascript, then the user's choice of file to upload isn't accepted and put into the VALUE="" field (stays empty).

I recreated it using js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6fays32v/1/

**HTML**

```
<div id="floor_plans_container">
    <div id="unassigned">
        Test
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
 var floor_number = $('h2').length;

    var html = '<div id="0" class="plan_page">' + 
'           <h2 class="closeable">Floor Plan '+floor_number+'<span class="rooms_count">    </span></h2>' +
'           <div class="plan_wrapper form_section">' +
'               <div class="plan_form">' +
'                       <form target="iframe_0" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="" id="form_0" name="form_0">' +
'                           <input type="hidden" value="0" id="0" name="plan_id">' +
'                           <input type="hidden" value="" id="room_ids_db_0" name="room_ids_db">' +
'                           <div id="buttons_wrapper_plan">' +
'                               <button class="save_changes" name="plan_save" type="submit">Save</button>' +
'                                   <a href="#" class="delete"></a>' +
'                                </div>' +
'                           <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="floor_plan">' +
'                               <tbody><tr>' +
'                                   <td>' +
'                                       <label for="name">Floor Plan Name</label>' +
'                                   </td>' +
'                                   <td>' +
'                                       <input type="text" value="Floor Plan 1" id="name" name="name">' +
'                                   </td>' +
'                               </tr>' +
'                               <tr>' +
'                                   <td>' +
'                                       <label for="file">Background Image</label>' +
'                                   </td>' +
'                                   <td>' +
'                                       <input type="file" value="" class="file_upload" name="file_upload"> &nbsp;' +
'                                       <iframe onload="" src="" id="iframe_0" name="iframe_0" class="iframe"></iframe>' +
'                                   </td>' +
'                               </tr>' +
'                               <tr>' +
'                                   <td>' +
'                                       <label for="room_size">Room Size</label>' +
'                                   </td>' +
'                                   <td>' +
'                                       <div class="room_size on"></div>' +
'                                       <input type="hidden" value="1" class="room_size_large" name="room_size_large">' +
'                                </td>' +
'                            </tr>' +
'                        </tbody></table>' +
'                    </form>' +
'                   </div>' +
'                       <div>' +
'                   <div style="" class="plan image small">' +
'                  </div>' +
'               </div>' +
'              </div>' +
'       </div>';


    $("#floor_plans_container #unassigned").html(html);
```

If you try to select a file, you'll see that the VALUE="" of the input stays the same - that's the problem.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're not doing anything wrong, that's just how it works. If you want to read the current value, use javascript.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript cannot alter the value of an input of type "file". It's a security thing.

Otherwise you could do something like run all kinds of hidden forms on a page and upload files via Ajax without a user knowing about it.

Comment: I'm not looking to alter the value - I'm putting the entire tag on the page for the user to pick a file. try to fill the VALUE="" by selecting a file from your system , you'll see it's not the normal behavior

Comment: No I don’t see that, I see the normal behavior I’d expect – after chosing a file, the input field shows its path on my local drive.